# Query single value with SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get a single value(aktiv) out of a table called wartung.

```
include('blog/includes/db_connect.php');
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM wartung");
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($wartung_id, $aktiv, $grund);
```

The value of aktiv in the database is 1.
but this code doesn't get this 1 into the `$aktiv` variable.

<sub>PS: I'm not used to code with MySQL and PHP so if there is a beginner-bug please don't be mad.</sub>

Comment: Now all you need to do is `mysqli_stmt_fetch()`.

Comment: Which single value?  The first row?  The last?  Some specific row?  A row selected at random?  All the values for a single column?

Comment: i need the value 1 out of the second position(position like this: wartung_id(int), aktiv(int), grund(text)) in row 0

Comment: OP can you post your table schema?

Comment: Did you finally do `$query->fetch();` as pointed out.

Comment: yep i did! But already fighting against the next problem... but this time i can handle it alone... maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
include('blog/includes/db_connect.php');
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT aktiv FROM wartung");// I am assuming your column is named aktiv
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($aktiv);
$query->fetch();
```

Comment: @JustinLandmann if you have got your answer don't forget to select Asad's answer

Answer (score 0):

You are not [fetching](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php) the value

```
include('blog/includes/db_connect.php');
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM wartung");
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($wartung_id, $aktiv, $grund);
$query->fetch();
```

Comment: I think the problem is actually that his schema is different from the one implied by his `bind_result` structure.